# In Jinja2, how do you test if a variable is undefined?

Tags: jinja2

Converting from Django, I'm used to doing something like this:

```
{% if not var1 %} {% endif %}
```

and having it work if I didn't put var1 into the context. Jinja2 gives me an undefined error. Is there an easy way to say `{% if var1 == None %}` or similar?

Answer (score 500, accepted):

From the Jinja2 [template designer documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#defined):

```
{% if variable is defined %}
    value of variable: {{ variable }}
{% else %}
    variable is not defined
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I believe this to be the case but my search terms often do not reflect that.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `{% if variable is not defined %}` to test the inverse.

Comment: @dannyman [Since 0.2.0](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/container_yml/template.html#jinja-templating)

Comment: `{% if variable is defined and variable %}` would also check for emptiness

Comment: @Vivek your answer ist the best. Usually I give my variables empty values `test: ~` and your solution could recognise that. THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 58):

`{% if variable is defined %}` is true if the variable is  `None`.

Since `not is None` is not allowed, that means that

`{% if variable != None %}`

is really your only option.

Comment: If `variable` is always evaluated to `True` when not None, `{% if variable != None %}` is equivalent to `{% if variable %}`.

Comment: If you want to check for `None` use lowercase `none` `{% if variable is not none %}`

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Do you have a link to documentation on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson This is the [builtin test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#none) called `none`.

Answer (score 22):

You could also define a variable in a jinja2 template like this:

```
{% if step is not defined %}
{% set step = 1 %}
{% endif %}
```

And then You can use it like this:

```
{% if step == 1 %}
<div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step active">
{% elif step > 1 %}
<div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete">
{% else %}
<div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step disabled">
{% endif %}
```

Otherwise (if You wouldn't use `{% set step = 1 %}`) the upper code would throw:

```
UndefinedError: 'step' is undefined
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use kind of Jinja **[Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)**

```
{{ 'OK' if variable is defined else 'N/A' }}
```

or additionally check emptiness

```
{{ 'OK' if (variable is defined and variable) else 'N/A' }}
```

**[Jinja templates - Template Designer Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if-expression)**

Answer (score 12):

In the Environment setup, we had `undefined = StrictUndefined`, which prevented undefined values from being set to anything. This fixed it:

```
from jinja2 import Undefined
JINJA2_ENVIRONMENT_OPTIONS = { 'undefined' : Undefined }
```

Answer (score 10):

Consider using default filter if it is what you need. For example:

```
{% set host = jabber.host | default(default.host) -%}
```

or use more fallback values with "hardcoded" one at the end like:

```
{% set connectTimeout = config.stackowerflow.connect.timeout | default(config.stackowerflow.timeout) | default(config.timeout) | default(42) -%}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{% if variable is defined %}` works to check if something is undefined.

You can get away with using `{% if not var1 %}` if you default your variables to False eg

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        var1 = self.request.get('var1', False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this in Ansible. Ended up having to do a test on both @Garret and @Carsten / @azalea answers, so:

```
{% if variable is defined and variable %}
    value of variable: {{ variable }}
{% else %}
    variable is not defined or is falsy
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -6):

You can do this :

```
- debug: 
    msg: "Executed only if variable is defined"
  when:
    - variable is defined
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it would be useful for anyone reading your answer if you provided more context on what each line is doing and why.

Comment: This is for Ansible; it has _nothing_ to do with Jinja.