# Jinja2 template variable if None Object set a default value

Tags: jinja2

How to make a variable in Jijna2 default to "" if object is `None` instead of doing something like this?

```py
{% if p %}   
    {{ p.User['first_name']}}
{% else %}
    NONE
{%endif %}
```

So if object `p` is`None`. I want to default the values of `p` (first_name and last_name) to `""`.
Basically:

```py
nvl(p.User[first_name'], "")
```

Error receiving:

> Error:  jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
> UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'User'

Comment: Make the function that returned the value of `p` never return `None`. Instead of `None` the function should return a proxy object that has the same structure as a real object but it is loaded with the default values that you want.

Comment: I use this, and my problem was solved:
 {% if p != None %}
    {{ p.User['first_name'] }}
{% endif %}

Comment: See also: [In Jinja2, how do you test if a variable is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3842690/562769)

Answer (score 410, accepted):

Use the [`none` test](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#none) (not to be confused with Python's [`None` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html)!):

```
{% if p is not none %}   
    {{ p.User['first_name'] }}
{% else %}
    NONE
{% endif %}
```

or:

```
{{ p.User['first_name'] if p is not none else 'NONE' }}
```

or if you need an empty string:

```
{{ p.User['first_name'] if p is not none }}
```

Comment: Notice the lowercase `none` in the answer.  My problem was solved after I corrected None's case.

Comment: This is the best answer because so many others do not differentiate between `False` and `None`. This example uses the term `"first_name"` which we can assume will not expect a value of `False`, but there are many cases where a system needs to treat `False` and `None` differently. Things like  `{{p.User['first_name'] or 'default'}}` will not catch that case and will convert `False` to the default case incorrectly. Other interesting cases are `0`, `[]`, and `""`.

Comment: it's kind of curious why `!= None` works but `is not None` don't and for this, you need to use in lowercase: `is not none`

Answer (score 174):

```
{{p.User['first_name'] or 'My default string'}}
```

Comment: This might be shooting in the foot when using with boolean values? I.e. if `p.User['first_name']` is `false` will the result be as expected: `false`?

Answer (score 108):

According to [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) you can just do:

```
{{ p|d('', true) }}
```

Cause `None` casts to `False` in a boolean context.

Comment: This works for a simple variable, but not for this question where you're looking to grab a field out of a more complex one.  I would downvote this, since it's not a good answer to the original question... and yet at the same time, knowing about `default` is exactly what I needed for my particular case, so... simply not voting.  (An edit to this answer might well earn it an upvote, except that I think it's likely hard to apply `default` to this situation)

Comment: I think the mention regarding `default` only works in *simple* data types is outdated. I have this working with an empty list, `default([])`

Answer (score 57):

As addition to other answers, one can write something else if variable is None like this:

```
{{ variable or '' }}
```

Comment: I am amazed this simplicity! Python's `x or y` is `if x is false, then y, else x`.

See:  [5.2. Boolean Operations — and, or, not](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: This worked for me where others failed.

Answer (score 24):

Following [this doc](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters) you can do this that way:

```
{{ p.User['first_name']|default('NONE') }}
```

Comment: I don't think so - the "default" template filter returns the default value if the value is undefined/missing.

Comment: Worked for me when using ansible. This made it more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28885184/1005215

Comment: If p is defined. But if P isn't defined it doesn't work

Answer (score 7):

To avoid throw a exception while "p" or "p.User" is None, you can use:

```
{{ (p and p.User and p.User['first_name']) or "default_value" }}
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me given my variable was buried deep in a dict.

Comment: This helps clean up some others with lots of logic.

Answer (score 7):

With `ChainableUndefined`, you can do that.

```py
>>> import jinja2
>>> env = jinja2.Environment(undefined=jinja2.ChainableUndefined)
>>> env.from_string("{{ foo.bar['baz'] | default('val') }}").render()
'val'
```

[source](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/997)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set your own default value instead of None than simply do this

`{{your_var|default:'default name'}}`

Answer (score 0):

I usually define an `nvl` function, and put it in `globals` and `filters`.

```
def nvl(*args):
    for item in args:
        if item is not None:
            return item
    return None

app.jinja_env.globals['nvl'] = nvl
app.jinja_env.filters['nvl'] = nvl
```

Usage in a template:

```
<span>Welcome {{ nvl(person.nick, person.name, 'Anonymous') }}<span>

// or 

<span>Welcome {{ person.nick | nvl(person.name, 'Anonymous') }}<span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As another solution (kind of similar to some previous ones):

```
{{ ( p is defined and p.User is defined and p.User['first_name'] ) |default("NONE", True) }}
```

Note the last variable (p.User['first_name']) does not have the `if defined` test after it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by defining a custom filter (in my case I needed in the cases `None`, False or empty strings):

```py
def __default_if_empty(value, default) :
    """Returns a default value if the given value evaluates to False."""
    return value if value else default

env = Environment(
    # Your config...
)
env.filters["default_if_empty"] = __default_if_empty
```

Then use that filter in the template:

```
{{ your_var | default_if_empty('') }}
```

Answer (score -2):

As of Ansible 2.8, you can just use:

```
{{ p.User['first_name'] }}
```

See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.8.html#jinja-undefined-values

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add "default none" to your variable as the form below mentioned:

```
{{ your_var | default('NONE', boolean=true) }}
```