# How to use register in this context? (Ansible)

Tags: ansible

Thanks for your time reading this (probably dumb question)...

I have the following playbook:

```
- hosts: all 
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python  

  tasks:
    
    - name: Get shard status.  
      shell:
        cmd:  |
             mongo node1:27020 --eval "sh.status()" | grep shards -A 4 | awk -F ':|,|/' '{ print $2 " ", " ", $5,$7,$9}' | sed -e '1 i Shard Nodes' | column -t
      when: ansible_fqdn == 'node1'
      register: shards_status

    - name: Get replica status from SHARD1.
      shell:
        cmd:  |
             mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.status())' | grep -E "stateStr|name" | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/"//g'| sed 's/,//g'| xargs -n2 | sed -e '1 i Server Status' | column -t
      when: ansible_fqdn == 'node1'
      register: shard1   
 
    - name: Get replica status from SHARD2.
      shell:                               
        cmd:  |
             mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.status())' | grep -E "stateStr|name" | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/"//g'| sed 's/,//g'| xargs -n2 | sed -e '1 i Server Status' | column -t
      when: ansible_fqdn == 'node2'
      register: shard2 

    - name: Get replica status from SHARD3.
      shell:                               
        cmd:  |
             mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.status())' | grep -E "stateStr|name" | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/"//g'| sed 's/,//g'| xargs -n2 | sed -e '1 i Server Status' | column -t
      when: ansible_fqdn == 'node3'
      register: shard3 

    - name: Get replica status from SHARD4.
      shell:                               
        cmd:  |
             mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.status())' | grep -E "stateStr|name" | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/"//g'| sed 's/,//g'| xargs -n2 | sed -e '1 i Server Status' | column -t
      when: ansible_fqdn == 'node4'
      register: shard4

    - name: Append logs.
      lineinfile:
        dest: /tmp/status.txt
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: EOF      
      with_items:                                                                                                                                                                                           
        - "{{ shards_status.stdout }}"                                                                                                                                                                      
        - "{{ shard1.stdout }}" 
        - "{{ shard2.stdout }}"
        - "{{ shard3.stdout }}"
        - "{{ shard4.stdout }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I want to have in one file (/tmp/status.txt) the result of the above vars (shard1,2,3,4). The issue is, if I run the playbook, I got the following message:

```
TASK [Append logs.] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
fatal: [node2]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
fatal: [node3]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
fatal: [node4]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}
```

Any idea of how I can achieve this?

I have tried accessing into the dic, running only that task from one node and multiple workarounds.. but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this failure is because each time you are guarding your tasks with       `when: ansible_fqdn == 'node1'`.

So when ansible is executing this playbook in node1, its executing all `node1` tasks and then when it reaches the `Append logs.` task it tries to dump the stdout from `node2`. But since we are running in `node1`, `node2` dictionary is empty, hence `'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'`.

One solution would be to give it a default value, for example

```
  with_items:                                                                                                                                                                                           
    - "{{ shards_status.stdout | default("") }}"                                                                                                                                                                      
    - "{{ shard1.stdout | default("") }}" 
    - "{{ shard2.stdout | default("") }}"
    - "{{ shard3.stdout | default("") }}"
    - "{{ shard4.stdout | default("") }}"
```

[default value for dictionary in jinja2 (ansible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885184/default-value-for-dictionary-in-jinja2-ansible)

---

But the proper ansible solution would be to change your playbook and way of thinking.

With an inventory like this

```
[mongo]
shard1 get_shard_status=true
shard2
shard3
shard4
```

your playbook could look something like this

```
- hosts: mongo
  vars:
    get_shard_status: false

  tasks:
    - name: get shard status
      shell: mongo node1:27020 --eval "sh.status()" | grep shards -A 4 | awk -F ':|,|/' '{ print $2 " ", " ", $5,$7,$9}' | sed -e '1 i Shard Nodes' | column -t
      register: shard_status
      when: get_shard_status

    - name: get the replica status
      shell: mongo --eval 'printjson(rs.status())' | grep -E "stateStr|name" | awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/"//g'| sed 's/,//g'| xargs -n2 | sed -e '1 i Server Status' | column -t
      register: replicas

    - name: dump status to localhost
      lineinfile:
        line: "{{ shard_status + '\n' | default('') }}{{ replicas.stdout }}"
        state: present
        become: false
        dest: "/tmp/foobar"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

With this way, if you had another mongo node, you would only modify your inventory and not your playbook and you also dont have to guard the `replicas.stdout` with a `| default("")` as you are always executing that in your nodes.

Comment: This works GREAT! Both solutions are elegant and give me the result that I was looking!! Thank you so much!

Comment: remember to follow the SO etiquette and mark the answer as accepted if it is, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done! Thanks again! Sadly I still don't have the privilege to upvote, but I accepted your answer :))