# Ansible - Use default if a variable is not defined

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm customizing linux `users` creation inside my role. I need to let users of my role customize `home_directory`, `group_name`, `name`, `password`.

I was wondering if there's a more flexible way to cope with default values.

I know that the code below is possible:

```
- name: Create default
  user:
    name: "default_name"
  when: my_variable is not defined

 - name: Create custom
  user:
    name: "{{my_variable}}"
  when: my_variable is defined
```

But as I mentioned, there's a lot of optional variables and this creates a lot of possibilities.

Is there something like the code above?

```
user:
  name: "default_name", "{{my_variable}}"
```

The code should set `name="default_name"` when `my_variable` isn't defined.

I could set all variables on `defaults/main.yml` and create the user like that:

```
- name: Create user
  user:
    name: "{{my_variable}}"
```

But those variables are inside a really big hash and there are some hashes inside that hash that can't be a default.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614027/jinja2-template-variable-if-none-object-set-a-default-value/19616065

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You can use Jinja's `default`:

```
- name: Create user
  user:
    name: "{{ my_variable | default('default_value') }}"
```

Comment: And if the default variable depends upon another variable. For example `default('/home/' {{ anothervar }})`, is there a way to concatenate those values?

Comment: Just remove the ' around the `default_value` and it would use a variable called default_value

Comment: Doesn't work if variable is nested like `{{ dict.key | default(5) }}`. It will fail if `dict` is undefined.

Comment: FYI, this will now throw an error: `[WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.`

Comment: @JordanStewart I had the same case - with nested variables. I posted an answer with possible solutions below.

Comment: will it pick another variable's value for default? "{{ my_variable | default(another_variable) }}" ?

Comment: @BernardoVale if the default variable depends from another variable. As on your example `default('/home/' {{ anothervar }})`. I had to do the following to get it to work with for example a path construction:
`{{ my_variable | default('/opt/'+ another_var_dir) }}`

Comment: This solution won't work if you have something like this: `"{{ custom_delay*60 | default(900) }}"`. You will get still "undefined variable error".

Comment: @Rohlik `"{{ custom_delay | default(15) * 60 }}"` will do it.

Answer (score 16):

Not totally related, but you can also check for both `undefined` AND `empty` (for e.g `my_variable:`) variable. (NOTE: only works with ansible version > 1.9, see: [link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters))

```
- name: Create user
  user:
    name: "{{ ((my_variable == None) | ternary('default_value', my_variable)) \
    if my_variable is defined else 'default_value' }}"
```

Comment: This is great, very useful.

Answer (score 13):

If anybody is looking for an option which handles nested variables, there are several such options in this [github issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35992).

In short, you need to use "default" filter for every level of nested vars. For a variable "a.nested.var" it would look like:

```
- hosts: 'localhost'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ((a | default({})).nested | default({}) ).var | default('bar') }}"
```

or you could set default values of empty dicts for each level of vars, maybe using "combine" filter. Or use "json_query" filter. But the option I chose seems simpler to me if you have only one level of nesting.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer!

Answer (score 7):

In case you using lookup to set default read from environment you have also set the second parameter of default to true:

```
- set_facts:
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ lookup('env', 'SSH_USER') | default('foo', true) }}"
```

You can also concatenate multiple default definitions:

```
- set_facts:
    ansible_ssh_user: "{{ some_var.split('-')[1] | default(lookup('env','USER'), true) | default('foo') }}"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are assigning default value for boolean fact then ensure that no quotes is used inside default().

```
- name: create bool default
  set_fact:
    name: "{{ my_bool | default(true) }}"
```

For other variables used the same method given in verified answer.

```
- name: Create user
  user:
    name: "{{ my_variable | default('default_value') }}"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a single play that you want to loop over the items, define that list in group_vars/all or somewhere else that makes sense:

```
all_items:
  - first
  - second
  - third
  - fourth
```

Then your task can look like this:

```
  - name: List items or default list
    debug:
      var: item
    with_items: "{{ varlist | default(all_items) }}"
```

Pass in varlist as a JSON array:

```
ansible-playbook <playbook_name> --extra-vars='{"varlist": [first,third]}'
```

Prior to that, you might also want a task that checks that each item in **varlist** is also in **all_items**:

```
  - name: Ensure passed variables are in all_items
    fail:
      msg: "{{ item }} not  in all_items list"
    when: item not in all_items
    with_items: "{{ varlist | default(all_items) }}"
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is quite old, but what about:

```
- hosts: 'localhost'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ( a | default({})).get('nested', {}).get('var','bar') }}"
```

It looks less cumbersome to me...

Comment: The problem is you need to repeat this wherever the variable is used. The question is how to set a default once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

[@Roman Kruglov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895077/roman-kruglov) mentioned `json_query`. It's perfect for nested queries.

An example of `json_query` sample playbook for existing and non-existing value:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    level1:
      level2:
        level3:
          level4: "LEVEL4"
  tasks:
    - name: Print on existing level4
      debug:
         var: level1 | json_query('level2.level3.level4')  # prints 'LEVEL4'
      when: level1 | json_query('level2.level3.level4')

    - name: Skip on inexistent level5
      debug:
         var: level1 | json_query('level2.level3.level4.level5')  # skipped
      when: level1 | json_query('level2.level3.level4.level5')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `if` statement:

```
# Firewall manager: firewalld or ufw
firewall: "{{ 'firewalld' if ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' else 'ufw' }}"
```