# Jinja2 failsafe template rendering

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 to create email notification messages, mostly error notifications.

Sometimes I get invalid or incomplete data about the error details. After all, it is an error condition when this happens. E.g. a dict item might be missing or value type could be incorrect. In such case the rendering fails, but the error notification has to be sent.

I can do following in the exception handler:

1. To send the template as-is. At least the type of error event will be known to the recipient, but important data will be missing
2. To send a backup template with just raw data. That would mean to maintain two versions of each message.

What I really want is to render the template on a "best-effort" basis skipping all errors. Is there a way to do that in Jinja2?

Answer (score 0):

Use [defaults](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#default) everywhere it's necessary. Also handles undefined variables:

> `default(value, default_value=u'', boolean=False)`:
>
> If the value is undefined it will return the passed default value, otherwise the value of the variable:
>
> ```
> {{ my_variable|default('my_variable is not defined') }}
> ```
>
> This will output the value of `my_variable` if the variable was defined, otherwise `'my_variable is not defined'`. If you want to use default with variables that evaluate to false you have to set the second parameter to *true*:
>
> ```
> {{ ''|default('the string was empty', true) }}
> ```

Or you could use [`none`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19616065/1431750) if you're creating more complex structures based on the data:

```
{% if p is not none %}   
    {{ p.User['first_name'] }}
{% else %}
    NONE
{%endif %}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not protect from errors like applying number or date/time formatting to None value etc. As I wrote I must accept inconsistent source data and I cannot predict all possible problems within that data.

Comment: Then I recommend using only safe values in your template followed by a stringification of everything else. Not ideal but at least you get the info in your email. Why not try putting the error handling in your code before jinja processes it?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The notification system is just one of several modules in a larger system communicating via RPC. I want to make it more robust and simple `"N/A"` on place of each Jinja's failed  `{{ expression }}` would be all I need. Such functionality seems to be not available - and that is also an answer to my question.