# Python code works but not when translated into Jinja?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to render all the elements in my array when there is an element there and when there isn't. When there isnt an element at that position I want to display that there isnt an exercise(element) at that position. This requires a short bit of code which works in python but not in Jinja. Which doesn't make sense to me unless I am missing a difference between the two languages.

The reason I wrote out the code in python first is because I have been trying for a while to get this working. I thought if I wrote the python I could translate it but I guess not?

Working python code:

```
dailyExercise = [('Exercise 1', 1), ('Exercise 2', 3)]
for x in range(dailyExercise[-1][-1]):
    print(x+1)
    isExercise = False
    for exercise in dailyExercise:
        if exercise[-1] == x+1:
            print(exercise[0])
            isExercise = True
            break;
    if isExercise == False:
        print("no exercise")
```

Not working Jinja code:

```
{% for x in range(dailyExercise[-1][-1]) %}
    <p>Day {{x+1}}</p>
    {%set isExercise = False%}
    {% for exercise in dailyExercise%}
        {% if exercise[-1] == x+1 %}
            {%set isExercise = True%}
            <p>{{exercise[0]}}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if isExercise == False%}
    <p>no exercise</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Python prints this:

```
1                                                                      
Exercise 2                                                             
2                                                                      
no exercise                                                            
3                                                                      
Single leg balance abd/adduction
```

Jinja renders this:

```
Exercise 2
no exercise
Day 2
no exercise
Day 3
Single leg balance abd/adduction
no exercise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, while it’s *possible* to create complex branching logic in Jinja, it’s usually the wrong place for it. Beyond the visual clutter of the `{% %}`, there’s just the fact that the template is for client-side code as much as possible, not business logic.

My first approach here would be to process the array in Python, creating a new one with eg `None` included for a missing exercise. Then simply loop through the new array in Jinja, [checking for None](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19616065/1749551), and render the appropriate HTML. If you need access to the index of the current item, you can use the [`loop.index` and `loop.index0`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/) variables.

Comment: A [view](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/?highlight=view#flask.views.View) in Flask is the code that responds to an incoming request after it's routed. It does not use the same terminology as other frameworks. You also don't *print* anything in a template; values are *rendered.*

Comment: Thanks. I was using ‘view’ as in MVC, but even that isn’t quite the right division. I’ve adjusted the wording.