# Jinja2 if statement, where MySQL date type is null

Tags: html, mysql, jinja2

I am generating a table using the jinja2 notation, within a flask app querying data from a MySQL database.

The html template:

```
{% for j in JRN %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ j[0] }}</td>
    {% if j[1] != '0000-00-00' %}
        <td>{{ j[1] }}</td>
    {% else %}
        <td></td>
    {% endif %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

producing:
[image]

Where Date, `j[1]`, is null, or ‘0000-00-00’, I would like the table to be blank, rather than ‘None’.

The `Date` field is of type: `date`

In addition to the if clause shown above, I have tried:

```
...

{% elif j[1] != '0' %}
   <td>{{ j[1] }}</td>
{% elif j[1] != 0 %}
   <td>{{ j[1] }}</td>
{% elif j[1] != 'None' %}
   <td>{{ j[1] }}</td>
{% elif j[1] != 'NULL' %}
   <td>{{ j[1] }}</td>
{% else %}
   <td></td>
...
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe this thread could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614027/jinja2-template-variable-if-none-object-set-a-default-value

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using HTML entities to keep that area blank
updated code:

```
{% for j in JRN %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ j[0] }}</td>
    {% if j[1] != '0000-00-00' %}
        <td>{{ j[1] }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if j[1] == '0000-00-00' %}
        <td> &nbsp; </td>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endfor'. You probably made a nesting mistake. Jinja is expecting this tag, but currently looking for 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.

Comment: I also added  {% endif %} after the first if, but it still didn't get rid of the None