# Airflow - how to execute DAG from its last successful instance run?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG that runs every hour and does incremental loads like :

```
select * from <table_name>
where last_mod_dt between <execution_date> AND <next_execution_date>;
```

---***execution_date here is the current dag instance execution date (1PM, 2PM...)

However, some hourly DAG's instance fails in between, hence want to ensure that next task instance execution picks always from the last successful instance only; so that no delta records are missed from the source.

For example:- current scenario

```
DAG_Ins1 - 1 PM - Success (last_mod_dt between 1 PM AND 2 PM)
DAG_Ins2 - 2 PM - Fail (last_mod_dt between 2 PM AND 3 PM)
DAG_Ins3 - 3 PM - Fail (last_mod_dt between 3 PM AND 4 PM)
DAG_Ins4 - 4 PM - Sucesss (last_mod_dt between 4 PM AND 5 PM)
```

The last 4th instance which was success only picks current execution date (irrespective of the last status)

Expected:

```
DAG_Ins1 - 1 PM - Success (last_mod_dt between 1 PM AND 2 PM)
DAG_Ins2 - 2 PM - Fail (last_mod_dt between 2 PM AND 3 PM)
DAG_Ins3 - 3 PM - Fail (last_mod_dt between 2 PM AND 4 PM)
DAG_Ins4 - 4 PM - Sucesss (last_mod_dt between 2 PM AND 5 PM)
```

However, the last 4th instance should have picked date from the last successful execution end status which was 2 PM in the above example.

Don't want to query Airflow metadata tables. Do this method:- get_latest_execution_date() returns the last successful/failed date-time of a DAG? Any other {{macro}} that would do the needful ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `prev_execution_date_success` macro.
This macro provide the `execution_date` of the last successful DAG run.

Your SQL can be:

```
select * from <table_name>
where last_mod_dt between '{{ prev_execution_date_success }}' AND '{{ next_execution_date }}';
```

Reference to all available macros can be found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#default-variables).

**Update for Airflow >= 2.2.0:**

The `prev_execution_date_success` macro is deprecated. You can use other macros for example:

```
select * from <table_name>
where last_mod_dt between '{{ prev_data_interval_end_success }}' AND '{{ data_interval_start }}';
```

Noting that Airflow 2.2.0 implemented [AIP 39 - Richer schedule_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) so it's probably make more sense to query the data interval directly as:

```
select * from <table_name>
where last_mod_dt between '{{ data_interval_start }}' AND '{{ data_interval_end }}';
```

Comment: Thanks Elad. Can you(or ManiK) shed some light on how to use `prev_execution_date_success` macro to trigger dag from the last successful execution date ?

Comment: @Elad Hi. I see the documentation of Airflow mentioning {{ prev_execution_date_success }} as deprecated. Is there an alternate macro? I tried using {{ prev_start_date_success }} but that is giving me task's successful execution date instead of DAG's.

Comment: @SR1991 Updated the answer to provide information for newer Airflow versions.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at those options to see how I can modify my code.

Comment: What is the format of `prev_execution_date_success`, is it a date (would suck) or timestamp?

Comment: @jayarjo It's `pendulum.DateTime` check https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html there is example in the table of macros

Comment: I see that result can be `None`... is it possible to default to some other date in such case? Or what happens.

Comment: @jayarjo It's more a Jinja question not Airflow, Airflow just uses the Jinja engine so all abilities of Jinja are available. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614027/jinja2-template-variable-if-none-object-set-a-default-value