# Raise error for undefined attributes in Jinja templates in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

By default Flask renders empty values for undefined attributes in Jinja templates.  I want to raise an error instead.  How can I change this behavior in Flask?

```
Hello, {{ name }}!
```

```
render_template('index.html')
```

```
Hello, !
```

Answer (score 25):

Change the Flask app's Jinja env's `undefined` class to be `StrictUndefined`.

```
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import StrictUndefined

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.undefined = StrictUndefined
```

If a template tries to use a variable that is undefined (except to test if it's undefined) it will raise an error.

```
Hello, {{ name }}!
```

```
render_template('index.html')
```

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'name' is undefined
```

Comment: For those using jinja directly (rather than via Flask): You can pass `StrictUndefined` to the `Environment` constructor: `Environment(loader=..., autoescape=..., undefined=StrictUndefined)`

Comment: And here is how to check for (TL;DR: `var is defined` ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842690/in-jinja2-how-do-you-test-if-a-variable-is-undefined - this works even if the variable is undefined and strict undefined in place.