# Python check if variable exists, including None

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template being processed that includes:

```
<td>{{ '' if group[2] }} {{ group[2] }}</td>
```

I'm trying to add the  to all items that contain `group[2]`. I want to include entries where a value exists including `None`. Currently the following is produced:

[image]

How can I modify `{{ '' if group[2] }}` so it runs for variables that have values including `None`.

Comment: This is django? Please edit your post to include the tag.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Flask but I will add the tag

Comment: Tbh unclear what your asking. is that even valid jinja2 code?

Comment: How do I mark a question as "already answered"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842690/in-jinja2-how-do-you-test-if-a-variable-is-undefined

Comment: @thegreatemu thanks that fixes my issue.

Comment: @KDawG yes it is valid, what makes you think it's not?

Comment: @thegreatemu I marked the other question as answering what I need, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that using [Jinja2's `is defined` test](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#defined):

```
<td>{{ '' if group[2] is defined }} {{ group[2] }}</td>
```